# Need an excel plugin to see underlying openxml

Tags: excel, plugins, openxml

Does anybody know of an excel plugin that can show you the underlying openxml (preferrably in realtime and with syntax coloration)?

I know I can rename xlsx to zip the search for xml but if someone knows of a plug-in that simplify that then let me know

Answer (score 2):

The Open XML SDK Tool includes a GUI for browsing an XLSX file with syntax coloration.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en

It can't look at an xlsx that is open in Excel though.  Excel keeps a lock on the files it has open, so nothing else will be able to open those files until they're closed in Excel.

Comment: Thank you but I was looking for something that can do it from Excel (macro that browse the DOM ?)

Comment: @frenchone, I understand, but I suggest you use the tool available while looking for the one that isn't.  :-)  Good luck though.